# Could iOS app read message inbox and send message (SMS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an internal project and want to make an app which could read message inbox, message incoming listener and send message (SMS) via the app without jumping out. Because of internal use, it won't release to the app store. Could any private API implement this?

Comment: The short answer, no, for security reasons and privacy protocols.

Comment: The long answer is "possibly, yes". No system is entirely secure as long as the data physically exists. However, determining a way to access said data is a point into futility.